# Canvas Scaling Function

Tags: android, kotlin, canvas

I am currently trying to create a zooming function using the scale function of the canvas.
THe problem now is that even tho the function is called the canvas doesn't rescale. Could anyone tell me why that is and if there is a way to make it update the size?

My function rescaling is the following:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        val x = event!!.x
        val y = event.y

        event.pointerCount

        when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                if (event.pointerCount == 2) {
                    scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
                    if ((fScaleX + fScaleFactor) in 0.2f..0.4f && (fScaleY + fScaleFactor) in 0.2f..0.4f) {
                        fScaleX += fScaleFactor
                        fScaleY += fScaleFactor
                        mCanvas.scale(fScaleX, fScaleY)
                    }
                } else {
                    moveView(x)
                }
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                llFields.forEach {
                    if (it.x1 <= x && x <= it.x2 && it.y1 <= y && y <= it.y2) {
                        println("FIELD SPOTTED!!!!!")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you calling `invalidate()` to get the `View` to redraw itself? If you are, you might need to post the `onDraw()` code and wherever you draw to `mCanvas` too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution! I just had to invalidate the canvas and thus call onDraw() again to resize.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).